# why p tag is excluding when I select through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a kinda data as like below when I select the `p` tag using its `classname` it returns `<strong>Packages:</strong>` but i want the data to be selected as like this `<p class="first"><strong>Packages:</strong> </p>`.

```js
alert($('.mydiv').html());
$('.itemize div p:first').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemize">
    <p> Order Summery</p>
    <div class="mydiv">
    <p class="first"><strong>Packages:</strong> </p> 
    </div>
   </div>
```

Can somebody help me to get the whole `p` tag including `<strong>` element.
Any suggestions, Please !

Comment: updated my answer to use `prop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
alert($('.itemize div p.first').get(0).outerHTML);
alert($('.itemize div p.first').prop('outerHTML'));
$('.itemize div p:first').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemize">
    <p> Order Summery</p>
    <div>
    <p class="first"><strong>Packages:</strong> </p> 
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `OuterHTML` , `OuterHTML` return selector html code.

```js
alert($('.itemize div p.first')[0].outerHTML);
$('.itemize div p:first').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemize">
    <p> Order Summery</p>
    <div>
    <p class="first"><strong>Packages:</strong> </p> 
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery code like this with `:last` :

```
alert($('.itemize div p:last').html());
$('.itemize div p:last').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: It returns null :(

Comment: @06011991, Updated my answer.

Comment: This should work.